# Are there CAT(-1) spaces which are not trees whose Gromov boundary is disconnected?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Are there some examples of CAT(-1) spaces which are not trees which have disconnected Gromov boundary?

Comment: Yes: let $T$ be (the 2-skeleton of) an equilateral triangle in the hyperbolic plane $H^2$. Consider two copies of $T$ glued on their vertices, and take the universal covering, with the length metric. Then it is obviously QI to a tree and CAT($-1$), but not isometric to a tree.

Comment: Second example (if you don't want something quasi-isometric to a tree): consider a horodisc in the hyperbolic plane. Then it's CAT($-1$) and its Gromov boundary is reduced to a point.

Comment: @YCor How is a point disconnected?

Comment: oh, I saw "totally disconnected". Otherwise it's even much easier, just take a wedge of two copies of $H^2$, then the Gromov boundary is a disjoint union of 2 circles.

Comment: This is homework; the question should be moved.  As a hint - you should think of examples of CAT(-1) spaces and their boundaries.  Then think about how you can cut spaces into pieces (or glue spaces together) and how the boundary changes under those operations.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the free product of any two word hyperbolic groups has disconnected Gromov boundary. For proof see t[he nice survey of Kapovich-Benakli.](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/PAPERS/bry1.pdf), section 7.

Comment: word hyperbolic groups are not exactly CAT(-1). (But there are many examples.)

Comment: You need at least one example for which you know that the free product is $CAT(-1)$; it's OK for the free product of a surface group with $\mathbf{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can not make it to be manifold without boundary.

You can start with a tree and glue to it many compact pieces applying  [Reshetnyak gluing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reshetnyak_gluing_theorem).